# Horizontal scrollbar doesn't adapt width styled with css?

Tags: html, css, width, scrollbar, stylesheet

I've styled my scrollbars using css, however, the horizontal scrollbar doesn't adapt the `width` as opposed to the vertical one which has a 6px width and works perfectly fine. The vertical one is a lot bigger and I don't know why? I've also tried using `:horizontal` but that didn't change anything...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post Your coding! We can't do anything without it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, for the horizontal bar, you should use `height`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3svX6/

Comment: Oooh, yeah of course! It's always the obvious things... Thanks!